# Boolean is not callable in a if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with my code because I want to make exception and the If statement gives me an error (`if allow_name(True)`). What is wrong with my code?

My code:

```
try:
    dates = soup.find('div', class_='row no-gutters align-items-center').find('time')
    _dates.append(dates['datetime'])

except:
    await ctx.send(f'This name is unavailable')
    print('This name is unavailable')
    allow_name = False

if allow_name(True):
    users = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-7').find('samp')
    for user in users:
        names.append(user)

    for date in _dates:
        date = date[0:19]
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        unix = date.timestamp()
        unix = f'{unix}'
        unix = unix[0:10]
        unix = int(unix)
        unix = unix + 7200
        dates2.append(unix)
```

Comment: You want to call `if allow_name == True` instead.

Comment: Is `allow_name` returning a Boolean or taking a Boolean parameter?

Comment: It should take a parameter and check if it's true. So if it has an exception, It wouldn't write it without the first list

Answer (score 0):

You should use just:

```
if allow_name:
```

so youк code should look like:

```
if allow_name:
    users = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-7').find('samp')
    for user in users:
        names.append(user)
        ...
```

python is really smart, and your should not use variable == True, coz, if it will be False, if statement will get it and move to False condition

Answer (score 0):

if there is a function called allow_name, you are overwriting it when initiating the variable "allow name".

change the variable name or if you just want to check whether the variable "allow_name" is true or false use:

```
if allow_name: #True
    ....
else: #False
    ....
```